# How to measure test density in a java code base?

Tags: java, maven, testing, plugins, code-coverage

We are using SonarQube and JaCoco maven plugin to extract test measurements, such as code coverage.

However, I find that the measurements we get are lacking and I would like to find a way to measure the number of tests per public method.

The background for this is that I noticed that it is quite possible to get 100% method, class and line coverage with a single test for a stubbed method.

**Method under test**

```
public Integer parseString(String value) {
       return null;
}
```

**Test**

```
public void parseStringShouldReturnNullWhenNullIsProvided() {
       Integer result = parseString(null);
       Assert.assertNull(result);
}
```

The example above gives 100% coverage, but does not provide any value at all.

But if we were able to measure tests per public method this would give a measurement of 1, which should be seen as a bad result. By adding another test for this method the measurement would increase to 2 and the new test would be failing, but the coverage would still be 100%

Does anyone know of a tool that extracts this kind of measurement from a java application? Preferrably something that can be hooked in to maven as a plugin.

Comment: Actually, your example shows that “how many tests exist per method” is as meaningless as the code coverage. Neither indicates what has been tested and having 1,000 poor quality tests is not better than one reasonable test.

Comment: @Holger - you are perfectly right. The quality of tests cant really be measured in any way that makes sense. I first thought that if you have a high ratio of tests per method you are more likely to have a test that gives some kind of value but this assumption does not necessarily have to be true. It is just a measurement along the same lines as code/test coverage. Your comment got me started on thinking about what a unittest is and what is enough tests. I have some ideas there now but it's out of scope for this question.

Answer (score 2):

Line coverare or method coverage don't help you evalutaing test quality and that's what you're after. Test quality can't be easily determined by looking at the number of tests per method or lines covered because it's largely determined by the quality of the asserts.

There are tools out there to get measurements like this. Many do mutation testing, the change the production code in memory and check if there ist a test failure. If there isn't any test failure, the operation that was changed isn't really tested at all.

I have successfully used [pitest](http://pitest.org/) before but be aware that this has a huge impact on test execution time, even with the history option enabled.